# How to clear or update the thumbnailPhoto in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory

I'm able to add a picture to AD with the below code

```
entryToUpdate.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"].Add(binaryData);
entryToUpdate.CommitChanges();
```

but when I try to update, I get an error (The specified directory service attribute or value already exists). I'm clearing the picture but it does seem to work.

```
entryToUpdate.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"].Clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. I had to commit the changes each time.

```
entryToUpdate.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"].Clear();
entryToUpdate.CommitChanges();

entryToUpdate.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"].Add(binaryData);
entryToUpdate.CommitChanges();
```